# gebish checkbox not getting checked

Tags: geb

I have a checkbox as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="replaceExisting"></input>
```

Unfortunately, the following code is NOT causing the checkbox to get checked:

```
$('checkbox', name:'replaceExisting').value('true')
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Geb docs on checkboxes](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/navigator.html#checkbox) are wrong:

```
    // in the docs; doesn't work.
    $('checkbox', name:'replaceExisting').value('true')

    // This works:
    $('input', type:'checkbox', name:'replaceExisting').value('true')

    // This works, too:
    $('input', name:'replaceExisting').value('true')
```

Answer (score 1):

As a work around, this works for setting the checkbox on:

```
js.exec("document.getElementsByName('replaceExisting')[0].checked = true");
```